# Find the elements of $S_6$ that commute with $(1234)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $\sigma = (1234) \in S_6$. List all elements in $N(\sigma) = \{\alpha\in S_6 \mid \sigma\alpha=\alpha\sigma\}$.

I know this relates to cycles and orders, but I am having trouble finding the order of $N(\sigma)$ and then the list of elements.

Comment: Do you know how many 4-cycles there are in $S_6$? There are ____ ways to choose the 4 elements participating in the cycle. Then there are six ways of forming a 4-cycle out of them (=the number of 4-cycles in $S_4$). This gives you a total of $N$. Because all those 4-cycles are conjugate in $S_6$, then centralizer has order $|N(\sigma)|=6!/N$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the condition $\sigma\alpha = \alpha\sigma$ is the same as saying 
$\alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1} = \sigma$. So since $\sigma = (1\;2\;3\;4)$, we are looking for all permutations in $S_6$ such that $\alpha(1\;2\;3\;4)\alpha^{-1} = (\alpha(1)\;\alpha(2)\;\alpha(3)\;\alpha(4)) = (1\;2\;3\;4)$.

I think you can figure out what $\alpha$ can be just by playing with that last equality. Can you take it from here?

**Hint**: I count $8$ different permutations that $\alpha$ can be.

Comment: Could you show me how to find one and I can take it from there? I'm having trouble. Also is one the identity?

Comment: Yeah the identity permutation $e$ is a possible value of $\alpha$. We can see this because we know that $e(1\;2\;3\;4)e^{-1} = (1\;2\;3\;4)$. Maybe another hint would be this: the permutation $\sigma$ can be written a few different but equivalent ways, like $(1\;2\;3\;4)$, or like $(4\;1\;2\;3)$, or like ... etc. . Just by writing $\sigma$ a different way like this, can you now think of what $\alpha$ must be so that $$\alpha(1\;2\;3\;4)\alpha^{-1} = (\alpha(1)\;\alpha(2)\;\alpha(3)\;\alpha(4)) = (4\;1\;2\;3)\;?$$

Comment: If there really are only eight, then it’s clear, I think, what they are: the things of form $pq$ where $p\in\langle\sigma\rangle$ and $q$ is identity or $(56)$.

Comment: @KylieO, what do you mean by "rotations"?

Comment: @Lubin, yeah you're right, but I was trying to guide KylieO to that conclusion on their own. But thanks anyways. ...

Comment: Quick, @MikePierce, should I delete?

Comment: @Lubin, yeah, but too late. Thanks for the thought :)

Comment: Is α=(13)(24) one of them?

Comment: @KylieO, yes it is.

Comment: How do we know (56) is the identity?

Comment: Since $(5\;6)$ switches $5$ and $6$, it isn't the identity.